# Enabling Multi threading (using partitioner)in spring batch job

Tags: multithreading, spring-batch, partitioning

I created a util to read from mutiple files and write to multiple tables. the util is working fine but its taking 40mins to load 300k records. I tried to enable multithreading in my spring batch job.but its not working.

```
<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="30" /> 
<job id="MFJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
       <step id="stepFileId">
              <partition step="partitionerFileStepId" partitioner="multipleFilePartitioner">
                     <handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
              </partition>
       </step>
</job>

<step id="partitionerFileStepId" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
       <tasklet>
              <chunk reader="FileRdr" writer="dbiwtr" commit-interval="10000"/>
       </tasklet>
</step>

<!-- This is to demo File Partitioner -->
<bean id="multipleFilePartitioner" class="com.xxc.MultipleFilePartitioner" scope="step">
<property name="filenames" value="#{jobParameters[fileName]}"></property>
<property name="extractLocation" value="#{jobParameters[fileLocation]}"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />


    <bean id="FileRdr" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileReader"
        scope="step">
        <!-- Read a csv file -->
        <property name="resource"
            value="file:#{stepExecutionContext['file']}" />
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <!-- split it -->
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean class="com.xx.LineTokenizer">
                        <property name="delimiter" value="," /> 
                        <property name="tName" value="#{stepExecutionContext['tname']}" />
                        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper" ref="mapper" />
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="linesToSkip" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mapper" class="com.xx.MapFieldSetMapper" scope="step"/>

<bean id="dbiwtr" class="com.XXX.dbiwtr" scope="step">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="extractorDataSource" />
        <property name="tName" value="#{stepExecutionContext['tname']}" />
    </bean>
</beans>




public class MultipleFilePartitioner implements Partitioner {


    private String extractLocation;

    private String filenames;


public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> queue = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
                   String[] tableNameArray = this.filenames.split(",");
            if(tableNameArray!=null && tableNameArray.length!=0)
            {
              File[] fileList = new File[tableNameArray.length];
                int i=0;
                for(String fileObject :tableNameArray)
                {
                     fileList[i] = new File(extractLocation,fileObject+".dat");
                     i++;
                }
                logger.debug("Number of tables to be Persisting..."+ fileList.length);
                for(File fileName:fileList)
                {
                  ExecutionContext ec = new ExecutionContext();
                                 String  tablename=fileName.getName().replaceAll(".dat","");
                                    ec.put("file",fileName);
                  ec.put("tablename",tablename);
                       queue.put(fileName.getAbsolutePath(), ec);

                }
            }

        return queue;
    }
```

Comment: Tell us more detail what is not working, any exception, or any unexpected result?

Comment: its taking 80mins to load 600000 records.

Comment: show me MultipleFilePartitioner

Comment: could you also show the code of your tokenizer, mapper and your dbwriter?

Comment: Updated MultipleFilePartitioner